# Physical or intuitive understanding of integration and differentiation of signals

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, integrator

I was reading about op-amp integrator circuits and would like to understand my below point.

What is the physical or intuitive purpose or understanding of integrating or differentiation the signals?

I went through the basic purpose of integration and differentiation concepts which basically conveys that we need in real life situations. Like, to find the area under the curve. To know how much work is required for example and how much some signals will behave in future. It is for that purpose we do those things.

How can I understand it electrically? Any example or intuition?

Also, how can I identify the places I need to use the integrator and differentiator for a signal?

Comment: read up on PID controllers, how they work, and when they are used. Examples include quadcopters, sous-vide, and anti-lock brakes.

Comment: I see no need to keep the question closed. It is about commonly known elementary operations and their circuit implementations. The five answers explain them comprehensively from different perspectives. I see no need for citations (however, EE is not Wikipedia with its strict requirements for citing reputable sources). And a general note: Such systematic closings of questions hinder rather than help our common goal - the **understanding circuits**. It would be good in the future, in addition to simply clicking "close", the closers would make an effort to write a well-reasoned comment.

Comment: I agree to the above comment. I think, the answers given to the formulated question - and the responses of the TO- clearly show that the question is not "opinion-based". In contrast, it has caused a substantial/technical discussion.

Comment: @LvW, Maybe you will click *reopen* above (below the question body)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I wanted to understand, could you also tell me, why should I do integration of a signal? Like, what purpose would it serve in electrical sense? Can you explain?

Integration, in the context of electrical and electronics engineering, is an essential mathematical operation that finds various applications. Let's look at some of the fundamental reasons and contexts in which integration is applied.

At the most basic level, the integral of a function gives the area under its curve. In electronics, this can be used to determine quantities like total charge (integral of current over time) or energy (integral of power over time.)

If you integrate a power signal (like the power consumption of a device) over time, you get the total energy consumed by the device in that time period.

The voltage across a capacitor is related to the integral of the current flowing through it. Mathematically, \$( V(t) = \frac{1}{C} \int i(t) dt )\$, where \$( V(t) )\$ is the voltage, \$( C )\$ is the capacitance, and \$( i(t) )\$ is the current.

The voltage across an inductor is the derivative of the current, and conversely, the current is the integral of the voltage.

\$( v(t) = L \frac{di(t)}{dt} )\$ or \$( i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \int v(t) dt )\$

In signal processing and communication, the Fourier transform (which involves integration) is used to transform a signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. This can help in analyzing the frequency components of the signal.

In control systems, integration is often used in integral controllers (I-controllers) to eliminate steady-state errors.
The controller output is proportional to the integral of the error signal.

- The integral of acceleration gives velocity.
- The integral of velocity gives displacement or position.

Convolution is an integral operation used to find the output of a linear time-invariant system for a given input, based on its impulse response. It's crucial in systems and signal processing.

In analog signal processing, integrators are used to design low-pass filters.

In the electrical sense, integration offers a mechanism to accumulate values, which can represent various physical phenomena like charge, energy, or displacement. It also provides a bridge between different domains (like time and frequency) and between various parameters of interest (like voltage, current, energy, power.)

> Also, how cai I identify the places I need to use the integrator and differentiator for a signal?

#### Integrator:

Use it when you want to:

1. **Accumulate** a value over time, like adding up how much current has flowed to find the total charge.
2. Smooth out a signal, removing sharp, sudden changes (acts as a low-pass filter).
3. Correct steady, constant errors in control systems.

#### Differentiator:

Use it when you want to:

1. Detect **rapid changes** in a signal, like finding sharp spikes or drops.
2. Let through rapid changes and block slow ones (acts as a high-pass filter).
3. Respond quickly to changes in error in control systems.

In short, use integrators to accumulate or smooth signals and differentiators to highlight rapid changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, much appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

## Basic idea

**Integration** simply means the *accumulation of something (air, water, sand, food, money, information, EE reputations, electrical charge, etc.) over time*.  Therefore, there are two quantities - *flow like* and *pressure like*, where the former determines the latter. In the simplest case, if the flow-like quantity is constant, the pressure-like quantity changes linearly with time.

**Differentiation** is the opposite - a *sudden change in the pressure-like quantity causes a large change in the flow-like quantity*. In principle, it is not correct to do so because there is a "conflict" between two devices... but it is still used (as in life some things are not correct but we do them and derive some benefit from it:-)

## Implementation

In electrical form, (most often) **integration** is done by *accumulating electrical energy in the form of charge in a capacitor* or (less commonly) electromagnetic energy in a coil. Simply put, a ***capacitor is charged by "pushing" an (input) current from an "ideal" current source through it and the voltage across the capacitor is taken as an output***.

**Differentiation** is done in the opposite way - an ***(input) voltage from an "ideal" voltage source is applied to the capacitor, and the current flowing through it is taken as an output***.

## Capacitive integrating circuit

Ideally, the input quantity of a capacitive integrator (the current) should not depend on the output quantity (the voltage).

### "Ideal" input current source

This is the case when the circuit is driven by an "ideal" constant current source. Then it makes sure that the current is constant when the voltage changes (it does so by varying its internal voltage or resistance so as to compensate for the voltage variations across the capacitor).

**Conceptual circuit:** For purposes of intuitive understanding, a capacitor can be thought of as a "rechargeable battery".  Let's then apply this trick in the CircuitLab simulation below by replacing the capacitor with a varying voltage source Vc. This gives us the opportunity to exclude the "inconvenient" time and examine the circuit manually (by setting values of the quantities and using the *DC Live Simulation* by hovering the mouse over the circuit)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNcavh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

... or automatically (through a *DC Sweep Simulation*).

[image: STEP 1.1]

**Note:** Don't take this idea too seriously, though. I use it rather to provoke your imagination "stiffened" by repeatedly reading the same textbook "explanations that don't explain". Although the end result is the same as the real circuit, there is a difference in the way of obtaining it. Here the voltage source is independent, and there it depends on the current through time.

**Practical circuit:** Now let's "turn on" the time to explore a true capacitor integrator by the help of the CircuitLab  *Time-Domain Simulation*. Also, we have to replace the input constant current source with a current-step source to start the simulation from zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fypT0w.png)</sup>

***Iin = 1 mA:*** The capacitor voltage changes linearly since I.t = C.V -> V = I.t/C. This corresponds to our real-life observations. For example (hydraulic analogy), the water level in a cylindrical vessel rises uniformly over time.

[image: STEP 1.2.1]

***Iin = 1, 2 and 3 mA:*** The higher the current, the steeper the curve (corresponds to the hydraulic analogy - the greater the water flow, the faster the vessel fills).

[image: STEP 1.2.2]

***C = 1, 2 and 3 µF:*** Conversely, the higher the capacitance, the steeper the curve (corresponds to the hydraulic analogy - the larger the vessel, the slower it fills).

[image: STEP 1.2.3]

### "Real" input current source

The circuit above is great;  there is only a "small" problem - there are no natural constant current sources. So we have to make them from a voltage source and a resistor in series according to Ohm's law.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdKV4r.png)</sup>

However, a new problem appears here - the capacitor voltage is subtracted from the input voltage and the current decreases (Iin = Vin - Vc). This is how the famous exponent is obtained.

[image: STEP 1.3]

### Op-amp inverting integrator

**Conceptual circuit:** To solve the problem, we can apply a well-known remedy from our life: Since the capacitor voltage Vc is subtracted from the input voltage Vin, we add an equivalent voltage Vout = Vc to the input voltage in the loop of three elements. This means to connect a voltage source Vout = -Vc in series to the capacitor (and the input voltage source), and adjust Vout = Vc. For this purpose, we can connect a *zero voltage indicator* (voltmeter VG) in parallel to the network of the two voltage sources Vc and Vout in series, and set its reading to zero (the so-called "virtual ground").

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4N1qZ.png)</sup>

As a result, the current-creating voltage applied to the resistor will be Vr = Vin - Vc + Vc = Vin, and the current Iin = Vin/R will be constant. Note that although Vout is negative in regards to ground, it has the same polarity as Vin when traveling the loop; so it is added to Vin.

**Practical circuit:** An op-amp can better do this work. Now it produces the compensating voltage Vout = Vc, and we can use it as an (inverted) output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa0v0Q.png)</sup>

In the graph below, you can see how the two voltages Vc and Vout are subtracted and the result is zero voltage (*virtual ground*). They change in opposite directions, and their difference is constantly zero.

[image: STEP 1.4.2]

## Capacitive differentiating circuit

As it is mentioned at the beginning, the differentiating circuit is based on the "incorrect" connection of two voltage sources in parallel (without any resistance in the circuit). This forces the current to change vigorously even with a small difference between the voltages. So, the output quantity of the capacitive differentiator (the current) should not depend on the load resistance.

### "Ideal" current load

This is the case when the circuit is loaded by an "ideal" current load with zero resistance ("piece of wire"). It makes sure that the output current is determined only by the "conflict" between the two voltage sources Vin and Vc.

**Conceptual circuit:** For convenience, we again emulate the capacitor through a voltage source...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsIVNt.png)</sup>

... with the proviso that the current only resembles the real one.

[image: STEP 2.1]

To limit the current to some reasonable value, I have used a little trick by setting some small resistance (1 Ω) to the ammeter.

**Practical circuit**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8HU98.png)</sup>

***Vin = 1 V:*** Since the capacitor is not charged (Vc = 0), a voltage difference of 1 V is applied across it. Theoretically the current should increase up to infinity but obviously the simulator has set some resistances to devices; so the current spike is limited to 10 mA in the first moment. Then the capacitor quickly charges and the current decreases to zero.

[image: STEP 2.2.1]

***Vin = 1, 2 and 3 V***

The higher the input voltage step, the larger the current surge.

[image: STEP 2.2.2]

***C = 1, 2 and 3 µF***

The same applies to the value of the capacity - the higher it is, the higher the current surge.

[image: STEP 2.2.3]

### "Real" current load

But there is still a "small" problem - the ideal current load does not work for us because we need output voltage and not output current. For this purpose, we include a resistor R to convert the current into a voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMCSh4.png)</sup>

However, this voltage drop is subtracted from the input voltage and changes the current magnitude.

[image: STEP 2.3]

### Op-amp inverting differentiator

**Conceptual circuit:** To solve the problem, we can apply the well-known remedy from above: Since the voltage Vr across the "visualized resistor" (the voltmeter R-1k with intentionally decreased resistance of 1 kΩ) is subtracted from the input voltage Vin, we add an equivalent voltage Vout = Vr to the input voltage in the loop of three elements. This means to connect a voltage source Vout = -Vr in series to the resistor (and the input voltage source). As a result, the voltage applied to the capacitor will be Vc = Vin - Vr + Vr = Vin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyZ4cU.png)</sup>

We can apply the same tricks as above (in schematic 2.1) connecting a *zero voltage indicator* VG, and setting some low resistance (100 Ω) to the ammeter.

**Practical circuit:** Of course, the ubiquitous  op-amp can better do this work. Now it produces the compensating voltage Vout = Vr, and we use it as an output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGlVCa.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2.4.2]

In the graph above, you can see how the two voltages Vr and Vout are subtracted and the result is zero voltage (*virtual ground*).

## Applications

Integrating and differentiating circuits were originally used to implement the corresponding mathematical operations in analog computers (I remember that time when, as a student, we were solving differential equations in the Analog Computers lab).

Now they are used for more prosaic purposes in electronic circuits. For example, a typical application is producing a linearly varying (ramp) voltage, first for sweep purposes in CRT, and later and now, in integrating voltmeters.

Indeed, there are also some more sophisticated applications such as the so-called *charge amplifier*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give an electrical example? Like, why should I integrate or differentiate a signal? Like, under what conditions should I do and what purpose would it serve?

Comment: @Freshman, I'll do it but this (like integration :-) takes time... even more so when illustrated with experiments (simulations).

Comment: Sure thank you. As I wanted to understand, could you also tell me, why should I do integration of a signal? Like, what purpose would it serve in electrical sense? Can you explain?

Comment: @Freshman, Here it is accepted that the explanations are given through answers and not through comments. So I started answering your questions in the body of my answer. Later today, I'll supplement these explanations with a series of CircuitLab experiments to demonstrate the ideas behind these famous circuits.

Answer (score 2):

Freshman, in your question you refer exclusively to the **time domain**. However, in order to understand the role of integration or differentiation in signal processing, it is useful and necessary to consider the behavior of the signals in the **frequency domain** - i.e. to analyze the frequency-dependent transfer function by magnitude and phase.

- By doing this, you will see that the output voltage of an integrating circuit decreases with frequency (and lags the input in phase; example: RC low-pass filter).
- With a differentiating circuit it is the other way round - increasing magnitude at the output with leading phase (example: CR high-pass).

Both examples already show that these properties are exploited especially in **electrical filter circuits**. Another important applications is in **oscillator circuits** because here we need a certain fixed phase shift (180 deg) for one single frequency.

The situation is slightly different for **classical control systems** where we have a closed loop which should react upon input changes in a certain way (e.g. quick and without overshoot). That means: The timely behaviour of the system has to meet some specific specifications.

For this purpose we need some shaping devices (e.g. controllers with integrating and/or differentiating properties) which work together with the remaining parts of the control loop.
However, also for these applications we need to analyze the frequency behaviour (frequency domain) of the closed as well as the open loop with the aim to analyze the stability properties of the system (Nyquists stability criterion).

**Comment:** Speaking about the "frequency domain" we analyze a system exclusively for sinusoidal signals. Therefore, it is rather easy to intuitively understand how an intergator/differentiator will behave:

- Integration: The integral over (sinwt * dt) will be (-1/w)coswt. Hence, the magnitude is prop. to (1/w) and the phase shift is 90 deg (between sin and cos). (Note that "w" is the so-called angular frequency w=2*Pi*f).
- Differentiation: d(sinwt)/dt=w*coswt. It is obvious that the resulting amplitude now is prop. to the angular frequency w.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Just a question. How to intuitively understand that an integrator, the frequency and output voltage are inverse and for the differentiator it is proportional?

Comment: OK - no problem. Please see the edited part at the end of my above answer-

Answer (score 1):

For a physical or intuitive understanding of integration and differentiation, you need look no further than distance, speed and acceleration.

- Distance is the time integral of speed
- Acceleration is the differential of speed
- Speed is the differential of distance

In the electrical domain, capacitors require integration and differentiation to describe their behaviour

- Charge is the integral of current
- Current is the differential of charge

For the purely practical reason that it's easy to get a near ideal capacitor, but not easy to get an ideal inductor (that pesky resistance complicates their on-the-bench observed behaviour) it's easier to see the ideal behaviour with capacitors. However, when you allow for the voltage drop through their resistance, inductors have the dual behaviour to capacitors, which is

- Current is the integral of voltage
- Voltage is the differential of current

The constants of proportionality are the capacitance or inductance respectively.

Remember that when you do integration, you get a constant of integration pop up in the equation? Most students try to ignore or forget it. However, it is the initial condition. If you take a capacitor that's already charged somewhat, then try to integrate the current, the initial charge is that constant of integration. With speed and distance, it's the initial position.

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications for integrators, give or take how ideal they are, or how "pure".  For example, we use integrators to make control loops with asymptotically low DC error; or when combined with gain and feedback terms, we use integrators to make electronic signal filters.

But real error amplifiers aren't true integrators, they have some finite DC gain; they are also (usually) compensated in such a way that they cease to behave as an integrator at some intermediate or upper frequency (pole-zero or lead-lag compensation).  And filters are a complex application of them, and may deal with nonideal ones (e.g. amplifiers of limited gain, or inductors or capacitors of limited Q factor), introducing further complexity in their use.

So these are perhaps not a good direct illustration of pure integration.

One example which is, by physical necessity, an ideal integrator, is time itself.  Or rather, when we subdivide it regularly: frequency.

**Frequency Modulation**

Suppose we have a sine wave at 1kHz.  What is its phase at any instant in time?  If the amplitude is constant (from peak to peak), and we measure the voltage, and we know it's been recently rising or falling, we can unambiguously measure the phase at that instant in time.  The phase increases linearly with time, and this rate is called the frequency.

That is, we have a signal,
$$v(t) = A \sin \left( \omega t + \phi\right)$$
where the phase at any instant in time is \$\omega t + \phi\$.  Simply measure the voltage, divide by A, take the arcsin (accounting for direction; there is a more subtle and complete way to do this (e.g. Hilbert transform), which I won't go into detail with here), and we have phase.

Suppose we have a time-varying frequency; frequency modulation.  Then we would have a signal,
$$v_\textrm{FM}(t) = A \sin \left[ \left( \omega + x_m(t) \right) t + \phi\right]$$
where \$x_m(t)\$ is another signal, the modulation function.*  Suppose \$x_m(t)\$ changes gradually (is bandlimited to much less than ω), so that we can consider it constant over a short period of time, maybe a few cycles, maybe thousands; stable enough that we don't need to know how it's changing within a given window.

<sub>*Which is a poor way of representing it; but again, to spare further detail.  Just intuitively: suppose \$x_m(t)\$ changed stepwise; well, granted it's supposed to be band-limited so that can't strictly happen, but a step change gives a multiplicative change in \$x_m(t) t\$ and thus the phase would be discontinuous.  Even if band-limited, the phase would wheel around worse and worse, as time goes on from zero.  To avoid this, we should take the integral of the signal over time instead.  So, to spare that integration, I'm hand-waving here.  This is mainly a problem of notation; we don't have this problem IRL because there is no absolute phase reference, everything is intrinsically relative.  (Or, we go to tremendous lengths trying to make an absolute time reference; WWVB, GPS, NTP, etc.)  When we vary an oscillator, we're varying some parameter of it like capacitance, or a digital counter divider ratio, and phase remains coherent from moment to moment.</sub>

When we measure such a signal, we can sample its voltage and therefore phase at a sequence of points, and thus measure how phase is changing over time.  If we try to express this phase as we did previously (\$\omega t + \phi\$), we have a problem: each time we take this measurement, we find a different value of either ω or φ.  It's inconsistent -- which was, of course, exactly the purpose of \$x_m(t)\$, to vary the frequency; an inconsistent signal is a signal containing information.  If we know this was how \$v(t)\$ was prepared, then we can take this as an assumption, fix φ, and measure ω from time to time, and thus reconstruct \$x_m(t)\$ by difference around the mean value, ω.

**Phase Modulation**

But we can *equally well* fix ω, and allow φ to vary instead.  What happens then?

Well, that would be called phase modulation.  And what have we been doing with phase this entire time?  Simply as time goes forward, phase increases.  That's it.  Phase is the integral of frequency.

Suppose we have another signal,
$$v_\textrm{PM}(t) = A \sin \left( \omega t + \phi(t) \right)$$
and we measure its instantaneous phase \$\omega t + \phi\$.  If we fix ω, then we can use it to subtract out the mean change (slope) of phase over time, and we're left with the phase relative to that baseline.

Suppose we smoothly step-change φ between two values.  Now the wave is oscillating "sooner" in a sense.  As if frequency went up momentarily.

[image: frequency is the derivative of phase]

That is, if we interpret a ramp-change in phase modulation, as a frequency modulation, we get a rectangle pulse in frequency.  Frequency is the "velocity" for phase's "position".

In other words, phase is the integral of frequency, and frequency is the derivative of phase.

This is as exact as we care to use it, because the integral is entirely a matter of definition.

When we use a PLL (phase-locked loop), we are able to match two signals within some margin of phase angle (which needn't be particularly stable, as long as it doesn't wrap around and skip a cycle), and then the frequencies are *perfectly* matched.  Which, if we use frequency multipliers and dividers around the PLL, we can even match two frequencies of essentially any arbitrary (rational) ratio.  Any frequency difference between the signals, is, necessarily and by definition, integrated to zero error by controlling the phase difference only!

**Further Reading**

The Wikipedia article on [Frequency modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) really does a better job of explaining it.  In particular they give the actual formula for a frequency-modulated signal:
\begin{align} 
  y(t) &= A_c \cos\left(2\pi \int_0^t f(\tau) d\tau\right) \\
       &= A_c \cos\left(2\pi \int_0^t \left[f_c + f_\Delta x_m(\tau)\right] d\tau\right) \\ 
       &= A_c \cos\left(2\pi f_c t + 2\pi f_\Delta \int_0^t x_m(\tau) d\tau\right) \\ 
\end{align}
(They're using 2πf instead of ω, and a gain term \$f_\Delta\$ to specify modulation depth.)  If we convert \$\int_0^t x_m(\tau) d\tau \rightarrow {x_m}^*(t) t\$ (using star to denote a modified \$x_m\$), we get the form I used above.  For a constant signal, this is trivial enough, but we quickly see the problem with my hand-waved representation when considering more complicated signals.